# Why can't I see some YouTube videos on my iPhone?

Tags: youtube, iphone

On a few YouTube videos, when I load them up on my iPhone, I get an error stating:

> Not available on this platform

Can anyone explain to me what is the issue with these videos that they can't be seen on the iPhone? (Is it due to size etc?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While uploading videos, the author has an option to enable viewing on mobile platforms. If the author's prevented viewing on mobile platforms, then you'll see this error message.

The error message [also comes](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/iDAHijDfynE) if the video contains some copyrighted media and the copyright holder has decided to not let the video be viewable on mobile platforms.

> If your upload has been claimed by a copyright owner, the owner may be able to restrict the devices on which the video is available.
>
> To learn more about the status of your video and the actions you can take, please visit YouTube's Copyright Center [here](http://www.youtube.com/t/copyright_center). You can also view answers to common questions here.